# What type of time variabel is the fastest to work with?

Tags: performance, time

I have thee different scenarios that I want to optimize.

> Lots of human input/output of dates with barely any
>   processing of them.
>
> Some human input/output of dates with some
>   processing of them.
>
> Barely any human input/output of dates with lots of
>   processing with them.

What type of time variable should be used for this scenarios if you don't plan to write all of the process your self?

Comment: run benchmarks.

Comment: It depends on the input and on the programming language you are using. Your question is way too broad as it is.

Answer (score -1):

Binaries should be faster value to process.

It only accepts two values:

```
Var = 0; or Var = 1; // ON, OFF and True, False
```

Comment: I mean booleans